# Aptana Resource Filter Regular Expression

Tags: regex, aptana

I'm trying to build a project resource filter using a regular expression to exclude certain files from the view:

```
index.php.20120316.bak

index.php.bak
```

Building an Exclude group (with OR, and Regular Expression checked) I've tried the following combinations:

```
bak$

.*bak

.*\\.bak

^[^.]*(\\.(bak|~))?$
```

Nothing seems to work for the file name with multiple periods or extensions. I would like to filter out any file that ends with bak regardless of the number of periods preceding `'bak'`.

Your insight on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `\.bak$` is the expression to match anything that ends with `.bak`. How you use and negate that with the tools you got I don't know.

Comment: Thanks Qtax, but I've tried that as well. The two files are in separate folders within the same project, so I don't know why one of them gets ignored by the rule.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
[\w.]+.bak
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT:

```
\w
Matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore).
```

So to go over it again it will search for one or many alphanumerical & underscore combination, it can have multiple point characters "." and it must have the ending .bak

Comment: Thanks Bogdan, but why the "[\w.]"? I don't understand the expression.